# Code Not Executing on Application's onCreate - Kotlin/Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Can you please help me understand why I can't run the line **SoundManager.initialize(this)** within Application's onCreate?

```
    class MyApplication : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    SoundManager.initialize(this)
    }
}
```

from

```
    class SoundManager {

var soundPool: SoundPool
var c3 = 0

init {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        soundPool = SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(13).build()
    } else {
        soundPool = SoundPool(13, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 5)
    }
}

fun loadSound(context: Context) {
    c3 = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.c3, 1)
}

fun playSound() {
    soundPool.play(c3, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f)
}

companion object {

    private var singleton: SoundManager? = null

    fun initialize(context: Context) {
        val soundManager = instance
        soundManager.loadSound(context)
    }

    val instance: SoundManager
        @Synchronized get() {
            if (singleton == null) {
                singleton = SoundManager()
            }
            return singleton as SoundManager
        }
    }
}
```

I've found a workaround by calling SoundManager.initialize(this) inside my first Activity's onCreate function, but I'm curious as to why I can't have it run with Application's onCreate.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your manifest? It seems like you didn't update it to use your class instead of the default application

Comment: Why one will pass object of whole application's context if work gets done by only activity's context!!

Comment: @Akash because it runs **before** the first activity's onCreate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
     <application
        -------
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        ------
       >
```

Add this to your manifest file.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Bedant!